# Why am I getting "too many connections" error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I am creating java EE app with Tomcat and MySQL. In hibernate.cfg.xml file I have set connection pool size to 10 
`<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>`

I have also created a DAO:

```
    public Rules getRulesById(int id) {
    Rules rules;
    factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Rules a WHERE a.id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        rules = (Rules) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return rules;
}
```

After querying the database about 30 times or so, I get the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/GoTown] threw exception [org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]] with root cause
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

I am not sure why, I am closing the session with: session.close();

Thanks!

Comment: What is your max connections setting in mysql?

Comment: The default max connections is only 100, so if you've got several copies of this running, even inadvertently, you could easily exhaust that.

Comment: @Shadow max_connections is set to 151 which is the default setting